# Symfony2 - Attempting to view my site in prod environment results in a blank screen; no errors/warnings in dev

Tags: php, symfony

Cross-posted from the official Symfony Google Group because time is an issue:

I'm in the final push to upload my site to my host.  Everything runs fine in the dev environment - no errors, no warnings.  When I attempt to access it in prod (localhost/web/app.php/), I get a blank screen.  I attempted to clear the cache, to see if that would help, but got the following error:

```
$ app/console cache:clear --env=prod

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException] 
The parameter "kernel.trusted_proxies" must be defined.
```

I can clear the dev cache without issue.

Please help.

Comment: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=67070&p=165780

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to add trusted_proxies to your config, even if it is blank.

Within: `app/config/config.yml` add:

```
framework:
    trusted_proxies: ~
```

You'll also likely want to delete your cache files (`app/cache/prod`) and then run your console cache clear (`$ app/console cache:clear --env=prod`)